# ios - I need to get the referencing outlet, or some other identifier from the sender (UITextView)

Tags: ios

Warning: I am new to ios development but not coding in general.

I am trying to do some validation on a UITextView, several actually. All have slightly different requirements for length. I have created a custom delegate to handle this but I am running into an issue with figuring out how to make it unique to the textview sending it.

I have several fields in several different nibs that will make use of this delegate. Most of the nibs will have 3 textviews labeled something like: summary, detail and special instructions. each of these has a different max length 50, 100, 130 respectively.

TL:DR; How can I get a unique id for each sender so I can do a switch on them?

EDIT: I also would like to update a label, hidden until needed, to count down the available chars left. How could I make sure I am accessing the correct controller and label?

Comment: Give them each a unique tag.

Comment: Tag, or in the delegates methods you transfer the sender, and check the equality between it and aSpecificTextView

Comment: ah, tag sounds like a great way to do this, thanks. I will try it and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your delegate protocol, define a way to send the UITextView instance along with anything else, something like:

```
@protocol UITextFieldValidationDelegate

- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField)tf textForValidation:(NSString *)newText;

@end
```

So that when the UITextFields call this, they pass themselves in for inspection by the delegate:

```
BOOL valid = [self.delegate textField:self textChanged:newText];
```

In the delegate, you'll implement this as:

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField)tf textForValidation:(NSString *)newText
{
    //compare to your IBOutlets
    if (tf == self.tfPhoneNumber)
    {
       //Do phone number validation
    }
    else if (tf == self.tfEmail
    {
       //Do email validation
    }


    if (valid)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing a variation of this using my own custom methods to allow for additional info. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to each textView, and check the tag in the delegate methods.

```
//In your viewcontroller setup
someTextView.tag = 0;
someOtherTextView.tag = 1;
someThirdTextView.tag = 2;

//In your delegate methods
if(textView.tag == 0)
    //do something
else if(textView.tag == 1)
    //do something else
else if(textView.tag == 2)
    //do a third thing
```

Comment: this is basically what I have started to do but I also want to update a counter (label) on the screen as well. Since I am trying to use this delegate for several different screens how would I go about accessing the correct controller and label?

Comment: It depends, if your UITextView delegate is the view controller with the labels, I would make the labels a property of the view controller, and in the delegate call do `self.someLabel.text = @"new text"`. If the delegate for the UITextView is not the view controller with the labels in it, then you would need to do something to get a reference to either the view controller or the labels to the delegate. Your code would have something like `someTextView.delegate = someDelegateObject` followed by `someDelegateObject.labelToUpdate1 = someLabel`. Then change labelToUpdate1 in the delegate.